# How to avoid creating snapshot on page bottom after selecting a feature on a VectorTile Layer

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-6

If you go to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html and click on any feature on the map, you can see that when you select a feature or multiple features from a VectorTile Layer a snapshot of the map is created at the bottom of the HTML page.

I am using the same method on my page and it shows the same behavior. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Use the dev version where the bug has been fixed https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/vector-tile-selection.html

Comment: thanks, if you make it an answer I will accept it